# Even defining object before calling query for a DataFrame, returns the error name is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def fl_base(df,file_name):
    columns = ['historic_odds_1','historic_odds_2','historic_odds_3','historic_odds_4','odds']
    mean_cols = df[columns].mean(axis=1)
    df = df.query(
        f"\
            (mean_cols > 0) and \
                ((@df['minute_traded']/mean_cols)*100 >= 1000) and \
                    (@df['minute_traded'] >= 1000)\
                        "
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
    return df
```

```
name 'mean_cols' is not defined
```

If `mean_cols` is being created before calling `df.query`, why is it saying that it has not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) documentation states:

> You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with an ‘@’ character like @a + b.

Here, `mean_cols` is your variable and not a `column` name in `df`.

```py
df = df.query(
        f"\
            (@mean_cols > 0) and \
                ((minute_traded/@mean_cols)*100 >= 1000) and \
                    (minute_traded >= 1000)\
                        "
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I believe `minute_traded` is the `column` of `df` and `mean_cols` as stated earlier is the variable.

Comment: Thats correct, ```minute_traded``` is column